# Flash UIComponent... not working... again

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, uicomponents

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: setSize is not a function.
    at circles::SpiroUI/doSliders()[/Users/wakemana/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4/SpiroPaint/src/circles/SpiroUI.as:74]
    at circles::SpiroUI()[/Users/wakemana/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4/SpiroPaint/src/circles/SpiroUI.as:42]
    at circles::Spirograph()[/Users/wakemana/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4/SpiroPaint/src/circles/Spirograph.as:115]
    at circles_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[circles_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:2]
```

I have included import `fl.controls.*` and `fl.events.*` and I've also made sure the Slider UI component is included in the Document library.

The UI keeps flickering in a strange way, seems to be redrawing the components in every frame or something. I did have this all working before, but since introducing some new classes, it's stopped working. The rest of the drawing within the application is working, just the UI components flicker and don't work.

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere something is not defined as the compiler is not finding the object which the function lies in.

Your stack has
*at circles::SpiroUI/doSliders() ... /circles/SpiroUI.as:74*

So if possible, you may want to update the question with at least that line to see how setSize is being called.

Another option to try is to set a breakpoint at line 74 and inspect what is available for the object before it reaches that error.

I followed what you had for the UI components to ensure the error was not from earlier.

I have a small Document Class `slider`

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class slider extends Sprite
    {
        var sp:SpiroUI;
        public function slider()
        {
            sp = new SpiroUI();
            sp.doSliders();
            sp.x = 100;
            sp.y = 100;
            addChild(sp);

        }
    }
```

And then I made a guess as to how you had your SpiroUI,

```
import fl.controls.Slider;

public class SpiroUI extends Slider
{
    public function SpiroUI()
    {
        super();
    }

    public function doSliders():void
    {
        setSize(10,10);
    }   

}
```

No way to know to sure for though, tried various ways to reproduce the error, but normally I would expect this if one were to be calling a function within a swf that is not at the root.

Comment: Thanks for the effort mate, there's no clear reason to me why this is happening. It could be because I tried using Flash Builder and updated the compiler settings to include Flash UI components... then again, this shouldn't affect it... *annoyed and confused*

Comment: Ok figured it out... it was because of the Builder export or something like that.. There was some conflict with Flex Component Base that was used in that process. I replaced all Library items, and problem has gone away. Thanks again for the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems like your `SpiroUI` class tries to call the `setSize` method which is not presented in the class.

Rob

Comment: setSize() IS a function within each Slider object. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/Slider.html#setSize()

Comment: From your error message and the rest of the question I didn't see that you are doing anything with the Slider apart from you have it in the Library! Good luck